# Streaming data fromhdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming

I am trying to practice Spark streaming with HDFS.

Code is available at the following link:
 'https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/HdfsWordCount.scala'

However, I am getting following error message
`java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD`

I am using Spark version 2.0.0 which is built with 2.11.8

I tried using sbt, running on local and standalone cluster mode but no luck.

Comment: can you include the line of code that caused that error?

Comment: @GameOfThrows : It is ssc.start()